# SQL Server building a dynamic calendar from table data and selecting data from other tables

Tags: sql-server, pivot, parent-child

I have this calendar table that specifies a date range period for each year. It has data like

**TBL1**:

```
start_date        end_dt        yr    period_num
------------------------------------------------
2015-12-27        2016-01-22    2016    1            
2015-01-24        2016-02-27    2016    2
2015-02-28        2016-03-26    2016    3
...
2016-11-27        2016-12-31    2016    12
2017-01-01        2017-01-01    2017    1
```

Then, I have another table where I have product entries such as

**TBL2**:

```
prod_id        weeknum      wkstartdate     postingDate     qty
----------------------------------------------------------------
1043890         1           2016-01-10      2016-01-18      3
1043890         2           2016-01-17      2016-01-18      6
1043890         3           2016-01-24      2016-01-18      2
1043890         4           2016-01-31      2016-01-18      0
...
1043890         50          2016-12-18      2016-01-18      1
1043890         51          2016-12-25      2016-01-18      2
1043890         52          2017-01-01      2016-01-18      7
```

Table AllProd2 is defined here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5836b/17

It basically  has details about a product and some hierarchy info. TBL2 has data for parent ID only but once I join the tables I need to display the ID with the highest priority number (if there are any child).

What I'd like to do is build a yearly calendar based on the period defined in TBL1. When I run the query, it needs to calculate a year from current week. then capture the data from table 2 for each period and build a result set with product details like this below:

it will need to sum up all qty for a given monthly period that's defined in TBL1

Desired result:

```
Prod_id     ParentID    Descrip Dept    SubDept Class   SubClass    Data-12/27/15   Data-1/24/16    ....... Data-11/27/16    Data-1/1/17    52wTotal
1043889     1043890     14 RD   abc     def     xyz     gty             9               7                       3               7           49 (summing up all qty for this product)
.....
```

I have a current solution that's outdated and uses several stages to do something somewhat similar but hoping to streamline this and make it efficient. Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: To keep things simplified, can anyone help me build a column view from those date ranges?

Comment: there are lots of examples of how to build dynamic pivots on here.. 3 or 4 pop up every day.. have you looked at any of them and tried to build the query yourself?

Comment: I have built some pivot tables already, however, I think this case is unique. Some of the pieces I'm not sure how to construct. I'll post a sample shortly.

Comment: I almost have it figured out. Just need one little help. so I have this calendar table here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8a9

Comment: I almost have it figured out. Just need one little help. so I have this calendar table here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d8a9 There are 2 flags (M, W) indicating Month or Week. I need to do a join with TBL2 (above) that has a weekly date field. so I will join item from TBL2 above on the weekstartdate with Cal table on start date (with W flag) but I need to return the startdate with the 'M' flag if the weekstartdate falls between start and end date. Does it make sense?